# sql query giving incomplete answer

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-timestamp

Need help on oracle sql for getting a subset of 'Dropped' data from 1500 hours yesterday to 2400 hours today.

The superset will be 'intransit' from 1500 hours yesterday to 1500 hours today

my query is only giving 'dropped' from 1500 hours yesterday to 1500 hours today

```
with A99 as
 (   
  SELECT shipment_id, 
         holder_employee_id
  FROM (
        SELECT distinct shipment_id, 
               holder_employee_id, 
               shipment_status_id,
               row_number() 
                 OVER (
                      PARTITION BY shipment_id ORDER BY CHANGE_DATE DESC
                      ) AS rn1
        FROM db.table1
        where (
                (TRUNC(CHANGE_DATE) = to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')-1 AND TO_CHAR(CHANGE_DATE,'HH24') >=15)
                or 
                (TRUNC(CHANGE_DATE) = to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                    AND TO_CHAR(CHANGE_DATE,'HH24') <=15)
               )
        and region_id=4
        ) 
  WHERE rn1 = 1 AND shipment_status_id in ('intransit')
 )
select distinct cs.tracking_id,
                ce.store_id,
                ce.store_name,
                cst.station_code, 
                case 
                    when cssh.shipment_status_id in ('dropped')  
                         and TRUNC(cssh.CHANGE_DATE) >= to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')-1 
                      then 0 
                    else 1 
                end as DAS_STATUS
from A99
inner join db.table1 cssh 
  on cssh.shipment_id=A99.shipment_id
inner join db.table2 cs 
  on cs.shipment_id=A99.shipment_id
inner join db.table3 ce 
  on ce.employee_id = A99 .holder_employee_id 
inner join db.table4 cst 
  on cst.station_id= ce.station_id 
where TRUNC(cssh.CHANGE_DATE) >= to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')-1
```

Comment: Did you meant o have both `>= 15` and `<=15`? Surely one should not have the `or equal to` part?

Comment: Your CTE only selects records that are 'intransit', not sure how you are getting any 'dropped' at all

Comment: There is OR binary operator with >=15 is for yesterday and <=15 is for today

Comment: Yes, but you will have a 1 hour overlap on each day, which I assume is not correct

Comment: Thanks John
 I have re-written the query using Left Join and its working